# Why does this QuickCheck test with a polymorphic signature pass when it should fail?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Given the following test code using QuickCheck, I would expect that `prop_Max errMax` should fail as the definition of `errMax` is incorrect.

This happens when I use the given signature for `prop_Max` with the concrete type `Int`. However when I give it the more polymorphic commented-out type using `Ord`, the test passes. Why is this?

```
import Test.QuickCheck

myMax :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
myMax x y  
    |x > y = x
    |otherwise = y

errMax :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
errMax x y
    |x > y = y
    |otherwise = x


-- prop_Max :: Ord a => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> Bool
prop_Max :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Bool
prop_Max maxFunc x y = (x <= maxFunc x y) && (y <= maxFunc x y)

-- in ghci
-- quickCheck (prop_Max max)
-- quickCheck (prop_Max myMax)
-- quickCheck (prop_Max errMax)
```

Comment: What error do you get if you try the other signature?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam, if I use  `prop_Max::Ord a=>(a->a->a)->a->a->Bool`, then, quickCheck (prop_Max errMax) will pass the test

Comment: Then what's your problem?

Comment: why would that signature cause error on test result?

Comment: What "error on test result" do you get?

Comment: If I use `prop_Max ::(Int->Int->Int)->Int->Int->Bool`, then quickCheck (prop_Max errMax) would Fail the test, bug if I use `Ord...`, it will pass the test like the `max` and `myMax`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with *defaulting*.

In `ghci` by default, the [`ExtendedDefaultRules`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) extension is turned on. That means that with the general `Ord`-based type signature, the `a` type variable is defaulted to the `()` type.

Since the only valid value of the type `()` is the value `()`, your test passes even for a definition of `max` that would be incorrect on a more complicated type.

With QuickCheck tests, you should generally be explicit about the type you expect the test to run on. So here you could keep the polymorphic signature for `prop_Max`, but explicitly select `Int` when you call `quickCheck`:

```
quickCheck (prop_Max (errMax :: Int -> Int -> Int))
```